# Rails Refinery styles don't appear in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

When I go to the Refinery pages index or editor on my production environment, I can't see most of the links or buttons because none of the Refinery styles appears. (But they do appear on my development machine.)

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to get those styles and images to appear?

All the config files in my 'config/refinery' directory remain untouched.

Comment: How are you deploying ? If it is Capistrano , check for the line `load 'deploy/assets'` to be uncommented in your Capfile.

Comment: Yes, I am using Capistrano. +1.

Comment: For anyone with the same issue, I had to alter my `config/deploy.rb` file to make the assets deployment succeed:  `before "deploy:assets:precompile", :link_db_yaml` and the `link_db_yaml` task should instruct `run "ln -s #{shared_path}/database.yml #{latest_release}/config/database.yml"`. Notice that I use `latest_release`, not `current_path`.